# Are these 2 SELECT statements identical? Weird use of ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm familiar with the ISNULL function in SQL server, but have never used it in this way.  I came across this code in the db I support:

```
Select * from employee where deptId = 58 and gender = ISNULL('M', gender)
```

It looks to me like this is the same as

```
Select * from employee where deptId = 58 and gender = 'M'
```

I tried playing around with nulls to see if the 2 statements would return different results but they were always the same.   Does anyone know if there are any benefits or scenarios where the first select is preferred over the second?   I'm on SQL 2014.  Maybe that syntax was useful on previous versions?

Thanks

Comment: both statements are same, no difference in output.

Comment: Maybe the original developer muddled the parameters and meant to default to male.

Comment: Maybe they meant `isnull(gender, 'M')`?

Comment: @APH: this is not different from `gender = 'M'` either.

Comment: Or else they may have meant `...and ISNULL(gender,'M') = 'M' `

Comment: based on the context, they wanted all 'M's.  Even though the statements are equivalent, I like the 2nd version better.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Yes it is.  It would return all records except records where gender is null (where gender = gender, but not NULL = 'M').

That said, I think possibly they meant to compare gender to something else entirely.

Comment: @aph: you're right, I misread your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These statements, the exact way they are put, are the same.

Using `gender = ISNULL('M', gender)` is not different from `gender = 'M'`

`ISNULL` might make sense in this scenario:

```
DECLARE  @gender CHAR(1)

SELECT  *
FROM    employee
WHERE   deptId = 58
        AND gender = ISNULL(@gender, gender)
```

, which would return all rows with non-null gender if `@gender` would have been set to `NULL`, and rows with the given gender otherwise.

If you are using this statement, make sure you have it recompile on each invocation, as the plans for `NULL` and a non-null value might be quite different.

This can be easily tested by creating a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
GO

;
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  1 id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id + 1
        FROM    q
        WHERE   id <= 100000
        )
INSERT
INTO    test
SELECT  id
FROM    q
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
GO
```

then running two batches with **actual** execution plan enabled:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @id INT = 7

SELECT  *
FROM    test
WHERE   id = ISNULL(@id, id)
GO

DECLARE @id INT = 7

SELECT  *
FROM    test
WHERE   id = ISNULL(@id, id)
OPTION  (RECOMPILE)
GO
```

and looking into plans and into statistics:

```
Table 'test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 337, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'test'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: thank you.  btw, in SQL Server your example will cause an index scan.   For large tables, that could be a huge hit.  EDIT: Even with OPTION (RECOMPILE) it will do a scan.

Comment: @mwill: if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or use it within a proc with `RECOMPILE`, it will use parameter sniffing and generate different plans for NULL and non-NULL values of `@gender`. I mentioned that in the answer.